# Unable to extract username by ID that comes from another model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, find

Seems so simple, but this one makes me crazy by now:

I got a Topics table, which has an user_id that is written during the creation of  a new topic, and comes from the User table.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation
  has_secure_password
  has_many :topics
  has_many :comments
  validates_presence_of :password, :on => :create
  validates_uniqueness_of :email
end

class Topic < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :active, :id, :opened_at, :title, :description
belongs_to :user
has_many :comments
end
```

Now the first thing I tried is writing the view like this:

```
<% @topics.each do |topic| %>
  <%= topic.user.name %>
<% end %>
```

Which drops:

```
undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
```

Then I tried another approach:

```
topics_controller.rb

  def index
    @topics=Topic.all
    @author=User.find(@topics.user_id)
  end
```

But this goes like:

```
undefined method `user_id' for #<Array:0x3c46fb0>
```

(If I hardcode any number instead of `@topics.user_id` then it shows the given user's name properly).

Any help is appreciated.

PS.: This is the way I save the Topic:

```
  def create  
    @topic = Topic.new(params[:topic])
    @topic.active = true
    @topic.user_id = session[:user_id]

    if @topic.save  
     redirect_to topics_url
     flash[:notice] = 'Success!'  
    else  
     render "new"  
    end  
  end
```

I guess the association is OK, because when I put

```
<%=h topic.user_id %>
```

then it shows the proper IDs. It's just that I cannot translate the ID to the user name that is stored in the User table.

Comment: Can you show how you are saving the `Topic`? It appears that your user is never getting associated with the topic when it's saved.

Comment: Go to your `rails console`. Enter - `Topic.first.user`. Does it return anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following in case `topic.user` is `nil`:

```
<% @topics.each do |topic| %>
  <%= topic.user.try(:name) %>
<% end %>
```

You should also remove `@author=User.find(@topics.user_id)`. This will raise an error because `@topic` is a collection of all the `Topic` instances and not a single instance (like `Topic.all.first` as an example).

Comment: What do you suggest then, please?

Comment: My guess is that at least one of the `Topic` instances has a `user_id` of `nil`. In the console, what would running `Topic.where('user_id IS NULL')` return?

Comment: Gives =>[]
I also checked this, and manually deleted the empty records with SQLite Browser previously.

Comment: OK, I added
<% if !topic.user.blank? %> into my view just before the line <%= topic.user.name %>

This revealed that there was a stucked record without ID. I don't understand it, but I restarted everything (Webrick, SQLite Browser), and now works fine.

seems that

Comment: My updated answer does just that. Also, you should consider adding `validates_presence_of :user_id` in your `Topic` model so you make sure that a `topic` instance will have a `user_id`

Answer (score 0):

You are using `@topics.user_id`, which is where things are going wrong; you are trying to call `user_id` on an array instead of a single `Topic` object. Use `#pluck`:
**Controller Code**:

```
@topics = Topic.all
@topics_ids = Topic.pluck(:user_id).compact #will remove nils
@authors = User.find(@topics_ids)
```

**View Code**:

```
<b>All Topics: </b>
<% @topics.each do |topic| %>
  <%= topic.user.name %>
<% end %>
<b>All Authors: </b>
<% @authors.each do |author| %>
  <%= author.name %>
<% end %>
```